# Objective-C Variable naming

Tags: objective-c, naming-conventions

I have a question about naming variables. 
I have noticed that many people name their variables with a lower case first, then a upper case. 
Is that just their way of naming it, or is there something behind it?

e.g.:

```
IBOutlet UITextField *addressBar;
IBOutlet UIButton *startGame;
```

Comment: Siply search the web for coding conventions. The help other developers to be less confused while reading your code, if you share the same conventions.

Comment: The variable naming style in objective-c is a matter of convention.  The question shouldn't be closed as opinion-based, because can be answered factually.

Answer (score 0):

This is called the Camel Case convention of naming variables and yes it is used widely as supposedly, it is easier to read. However, it is recommended to use underscores in most cases as they're much easier to read, especially if your code is going to be maintained by someone whose native language is not English, so:- 
IB_outlet *start_game etc can be used.

Basically, just use whatever convention you want (see-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29), just make sure it is easy to read and stick to it.

Comment: I think this is down voted because it asserts without evidence: "it is recommended to use underscores", and, "they are much easier to read", and, "just use whatever convention you want".

Comment: Camel case is the standard naming convention across all of the ObjC world. There is more variability around eg brace styles.

Comment: When I said use whatever convention you want, I thought it was understood that the reader will use one of the conventions from the link provided. Apologies for any confusion.